# What happens when you use Yorick's ultimate on Karthus?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Karthus's passive kick in before or after Yorick's ultimate goes off? Or does the  Death Defied work both times that Karthus "dies"?

Answer (score 3):

In a patch a few months ago they established an order of operations for all of the post-death effects. I'll try to find it and link it here, but I know that these 2 effects occur in this order:

1. Karthus is ulted by Yorick and dies
2. Karthus gets to run around as Yoricks Ghost
3. Karthus passive kicks in and he can cast spells but not move

**EDIT**

I can only find a link to the [Riot patch](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/release-notes-v100113) where they define the order for death *preventing* effects.

On the [LeagueOfLegends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Death#Post-death_events), we have an order defined for after-death effects which appears accurate to me.

Comment: It'd be nice to get the order of operations for all the post-death effects, but thanks for the info so far!

Answer (score 0):

Yorick ult will come first so that Karthus gets a few extra seconds of being alive before he dies and enters Lich Form.